# How to get BACKEND_URL from environment variable in saleor storefront

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, storefront, saleor

Saleor Storefront using EnvironmentPlugin of webpack

Like
`new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(["npm_package_version", "BACKEND_URL"])`

My .env file

```
# .evn
npm_package_version = 6.4.1
BACKEND_URL = https://demo.getsaleor.com
```

In my Index file

`console.log("env",process.env.BACKEND_URL) is undefined`

On start project as development Log

`WARNING in EnvironmentPlugin - BACKEND_URL environment variable is undefined.`

I set Default value like this 
`new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({'BACKEND_URL': 'https://demo.getsaleor.com'})`

This is working fine but i need to get value from .env file 
**Please help me solve this problem**

Comment: this app is not base  on create-react-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.env` files are not picked up by themselves. You need to use a package in order to specify the file in which you've defined your environment variables.

You can use `dotenv` for nodejs and `DotenvPlugin` for webpack in order to expose your environment variables through `.env` file.

[DotenvPlugin for webpack](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/#dotenvplugin)

[dotenv package for nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Hope this helps. Happy coding !